# Getting a NaN instead of my first value when trying to label peaks on spectrum graph?

Tags: python, scipy

I have been attempting to plot some element spectra using data from CCDs.

I have managed to convert pixels to wavelength okay, and have identified my peaks and found the FWHM of these. I would like to label my plot with the FWHM of each peak, and was successful doing so for the second of the two - but for some reason, while my method works for that one, my first peak is being labelled with a NaN.

I used the below code to try to automate the process of peak labelling as I will have to do this for other spectra too:

```py
#finding the peaks using scipy.signal, height specific to my data
peaks, properties = find_peaks(intensity, height=5000) 

#trying to find FWHM using peak_widths
widths, width_heights, left_ips, right_ips = peak_widths(intensity, peaks, rel_height=0.5) 

#scale fwhm with pixel to wavelength scale (found this by ratios, specific to my CCD)
fwhm = widths*0.02455085784313791  

#attempting to plot
plt.title('Spectrum of Helium') 
plt.xlabel('Wavelength, nm')
plt.ylabel('Intensity, counts')
plt.plot(x, intensity) 

for i in range(len(peaks)):
    plt.text(x[peaks[i]], intensity[peaks[i]], fwhm[i] % i)

plt.show()
```

The values of FWHM I should be getting are 0.15284472 and 0.10799707. Instead, by using this method, I am getting a NaN value as my label for peak 1 while it is labelling the second peak correctly with 0.10799707.

[image: Spectrum of Helium with one correctly labelled peak]

This can be seen in the above image. I'm not sure where the issue could lie beyond an indexing issue, but I haven't been able to change the for loop without breaking the labels entirely. Not sure why it would be working for the second value but giving NaN for the first.

Any advice appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the issue to arise from one of two places. Try the following to debug the code.

1. `print(fwhm)` If `fwhm[0]` is `NaN`, then you will need to debug why this happens.
2. Since the `i` is 0 in the first iteration, the modulo operation is not defined. Perhaps your code does not need modulo or you need to use `i+1` for the modulo.

As a note, please provide code that can be easily reproduced to get a quick and accurate answer.

Comment: I should have clarified, I have checked fwhm[0] and it prints the correct value. It was the modulo operation that was causing issues. Thank you